# Robot Framework Check of an Icon element in a table

Tags: css, robotframework

Hello I'm new to Robot Framework and I want to know if there is a way to check an icon which is embedded in a table row.
I use the Selenium2Library and RIDE.
I want to check that the used icon for the status of a table entry correspond to the status: a pencil icon for draft and a lock icon for approved.
I have two tables in my page, one in status draft another in status approved
When I do a check with `Page Should Contain Element    css=.fa.fa-pencil.fa-2x` the result is always true but it is not checked that the icon is with the right status.
I didn't find any keyword like Table should contain element.
Is there a way to do my check?

Here is the content of the table:

```
                                <td class="heading"><i class="fa fa-bolt fa-2x-tom"></i></td>

                            <td class="heading">ID</td>
                            <td style="width: 80px;" class="heading">Name</td>
                            <td class="heading">Type</td>
                            <td class="heading">RC</td>
                            <td class="heading">Status</td>

                            <td onclick="toggle('bom_info_1-3-4581-null-0', false)" class="heading"><i style="color: white;" class="fa fa-info-circle fa-2x-tom"></i></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>

                                <td class="padding-3 addBomSupplementalButton"><i style="color: green;" class="fa fa-plus fa-2x "></i></td>

                            <td class="padding-3">1/3/4581/null/0</td>
                            <td class="padding-3">3PP - Line &amp; Antenna</td>
                            <td class="padding-3">0</td>
                            <td class="padding-3"></td>
                            <td id="bomStatusOrigin" class="padding-3 bomStatus" style="color: green;"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-lock "></i> approved</td>

                           <td onclick="toggle('bom_product_1-3-4581-null-0', true)" class="padding-3"><i style="color: black; display: inline-block;" class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x" id="bom_product_1-3-4581-null-0_up"></i>
                                    <i style="color: black; display: none;" class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-2x" id="bom_product_1-3-4581-null-0_down"></i></td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
```

What I need is a possibility to check that the class `.fa.fa-lock.fa-2x` is in the same table then the text approved.

Comment: I dont see css=.fa.fa-pencil.fa-2x in your html . Also your question is little bit confusing. Can you please rephrase it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this elements is always contained within the webpage but it doesn't have to be visible. Try something like:

```
Wait Until Page Contains Element    ${locator}
```

or

```
Page Should Contain Element    ${locator}
```